# How to map the csv files Header names to the db Table while importing the data to db

Tags: java, csv

I have written the program. how to i map the column one to "Slno" , column two to "COM_BUS".Since, csv file does not contains correct headers as that of Table.
Example:
        CSV file headers has "sln"    "C_BUS"

Table "Business"  has column has "SLNO"   "COMBUS".

My question is csv file headers should not be the concern while importing the data to the db2 table. Please help.

private static final

```
String SQL_INSERT = "INSERT INTO OPTYMGT.${table}(${keys}, RUN_TS)   
                       VALUES(${values}, current_timestamp)";

private static final String TABLE_REGEX = "\\$\\{table\\}";
private static final String KEYS_REGEX = "\\$\\{keys\\}";
private static final String VALUES_REGEX = "\\$\\{values\\}";

private char seprator= ',';




public boolean loadCSV(Connection connection,String csvFile, String tableName) throws Exception {
    boolean  result = true;
    CSVReader csvReader = null;
    if(connection == null) {
        throw new Exception("Not a valid connection.");
    }
    try {

        csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile), this.seprator);
        //System.out.println("csvReader" +csvReader);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Error occured while executing file. "
                + e.getMessage());
    }

    String[] headerRow = csvReader.readNext();

    //System.out.println("headerRow" +headerRow);

    if (null == headerRow) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
                "No columns defined in given CSV file." +
                "Please check the CSV file format.");
    }

    String questionmarks = StringUtils.repeat("?,", headerRow.length);
    questionmarks = (String) questionmarks.subSequence(0, questionmarks.length() - 1);
    String query = SQL_INSERT.replaceFirst(TABLE_REGEX, tableName);
    query = query.replaceFirst(KEYS_REGEX, StringUtils.join(headerRow, ","));
    query = query.replaceFirst(VALUES_REGEX, questionmarks);

    //System.out.println("Query: " + query);

/*  SimpleDateFormat cDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");
    Date now = new Date();
    String ccDate = cDate.format(now);
    System.out.println("ccdate" +ccDate);*/

    String[] nextLine;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
```

Comment: So, you're saying this program reads the column names from the first row of the CSV, but you want to ignore that first row and use different column-names? If so: you you know the column names up front and can you hard-code them in the SQL, or do you want to look at the dataabse and figure out the column names at run-time?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are attempting to re-write the `IMPORT` and `LOAD` utilities?

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar situation and a workaround was to use the Java properties package to create a config file that maps bean variables to headers. I used `opencsv` to map csv to Java objects. However, before that I check if the file has headers and if not, I write headers to the first line of the csv. Since I use `opencsv`, I annotated the class variables to define the mapping. I hope it helps.

I am happy to share the code after the holidays